# The path of the images are right but not showing in the browser?

Tags: javascript, aframe

Example: http://vrviewer.istaging.co/#!/934520

The images aren't showing up. But if you copy their URL from their `src`:

```
<a-sky radius="7000" material="color:#FFF;shader:flat;opacity:1;src:url(https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/teststaging.com.tw//other/web/14666108560_Raw.vr.720.jpg)" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/teststaging.com.tw//other/web/14666108560_Raw.vr.720.jpg"></a-sky>
```

The image shows up:

https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/teststaging.com.tw//other/web/14666108560_Raw.vr.720.jpg

What could be the reason?

(Note: when the image first loads it has a status `304` Not modified. Not sure if this is the reason.)

(Note 2: the same website loads images coming from a different server: http://vrviewer.istaging.co/#!/57e4a8a48ac247005bb91fc7.)

**EDIT:**

The `<a-sky>` tag belongs to [a-frame](https://aframe.io/).

Comment: you may want to expand the question, regarding what an `<a-sky` tag is for a start

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated the question.

Comment: Consider adding an [aframe](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/aframe/info) tag, including console errors and warnings reported, and providing a minimal test case. Looking at the page link source, after disabling style sheets to do so, to find links to app.js files, to manually download for  analysis is some deterrent.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have an invalid entity in your code. Remove that and everything looks fine.